# Autoincrement with SQLite in objective c

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I want to insert an element in my table :

```
events(eventID int primary key autoincrement,type text,date date,coordinates text,deviceID int,userID int)
```

how the auto increment works?
in fact when I did not write the id I have an error like "you have 6 columns but 5 were supplied."
and if I just write nil I have always id=0, this is what I wrote :

```
insert into events(type,date,coordinates,deviceId,userID) values('%@','%@','%@','%d','%d');
```

thanks by advance

Comment: Maybe you can try to insert NULL for the primary key. It will autoincrement by itself. Something like : `insert into events(eventID,type,date,coordinates,deviceId,userID) values(NULL,'%@','%@','%@','%d','%d');`

Comment: thanks for your answer but by inserting nil, the id is always equal to 0 !

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) says that

> if a rowid table has a primary key that consists of a single column and the declared type of that column is "INTEGER" in any mixture of upper and lower case, then the column becomes an alias for the rowid. […] A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an integer primary key if the declared type name is exactly "INTEGER". **Other integer type names like "INT" or "BIGINT" or "SHORT INTEGER" or "UNSIGNED INTEGER" causes the primary key column to behave as an ordinary table column** with integer affinity and a unique index, not as an alias for the rowid.

Comment: thanks a lot I corrected it but I still have 0 for all the id !